# UITableView hidden header?

Tags: uitableview, header, ios

How do I make a header for a `UITableView` that is viewable when the `UITableView` is pulled down, but it hides when the `UITableView` is released? (Like the twitter app for iPod)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean the "Release to refresh" block more info can be found here [Pull to refresh by Dr Touch](http://www.drobnik.com/touch/2009/12/how-to-make-a-pull-to-reload-tableview-just-like-tweetie-2/)

If you mean hidden search field on top of UITableView, it's a cell and it's not hidden when user releases it. You can hide it when "something happens" by setting contentOffset property of UITableView by the height of search field cell.

Comment: I mean "Pull to Refresh", but I just want to show a static view there v